# Reshape2: multiple observations for variable

Tags: r, casting, reshape2

I have the following sample data:

```
d <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2), time=c(1,1,1,1,1), var=runif(5))
  id time         var
1  1    1 0.373448545
2  1    1 0.007007124
3  1    1 0.840572603
4  2    1 0.684893481
5  2    1 0.822581501
```

I want to reshape this `data.frame` to `wide` format using `dcast` such that the output is the following:

```
  id     var.1       var.2     var.3
1  1 0.3734485 0.007007124 0.8405726
2  2 0.6848935 0.822581501        NA
```

Does anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a sequence column, `seq`, by `id` and then use `dcast`:

```
library(reshape2)

set.seed(123)
d <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2), time=c(1,1,1,1,1), var=runif(5))

d2 <- transform(d, seq = ave(id, id, FUN = seq_along))
dcast(d2, id ~ seq, value.var = "var")
```

giving:

```
  id       1       2       3
1  1 0.28758 0.78831 0.40898
2  2 0.88302 0.94047     NaN
```

Comment: Interesting - this code works well on the example data. But when I use this code on my original data, the output for row number one is not spread horizontally along the variables (like we want to) but vertically such that it is pasted in row two and three for variable 1. Does anyone know why this is the case? The transformation worked well.

Answer (score 2):

A `dplyr/tidyr` option with `spread` would be

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
d %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(n1= paste0("var.",row_number())) %>% 
  spread(n1, var) %>%
  select(-time)
#      id     var.1       var.2     var.3
#    (int)     (dbl)       (dbl)     (dbl)
#1     1 0.3734485 0.007007124 0.8405726
#2     2 0.6848935 0.822581501        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok - here's a working solution. The key is to add a counting variable. My solution for this is a bit complicated - maybe you can come up with something better.

```
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
library(reshape2)

d <- data.frame(id=c(1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3), time=c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1), var=runif(9))

group_by(d, id) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  data.frame() -> count

f <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(count)) {
  f <- c(f, 1:count$n[i])
}

d <- data.frame(d, f)

dcast(d, id ~ f, value.var = "var")
```